# CakePHP 2.x: ACL Behavior vs ACL Component

Tags: cakephp, acl

I have read book.cakephp articles on [ACL Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/acl.html) & [ACL Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html), but I am still not clear on their distinction.

i.e., when is it best to use both? ACLBehavior only? ACLComponent only? If you can provide some simple usage examples accentuating these three different cases, that would certainly help my understanding...

My specific scenario, in case you want to finetune your answer to it: I want to implement a HABTM ACL with nested user groups; I plan to achieve this with the aid of [TinyAuth](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/) or [Ceeram's Authorize plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/Authorize).

Note: I believe I do grasp the distinction between Behavior vs Component in general; I am just confused about ACL implementation of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use both ACL Behavior & ACL Component to implement Access Control List in your application. ACL Behavior is used in Model where you can declare `public $actsAs` variable to tell the behavior to act as requester (ARO) or that this model should be `controlled` (ACO) or both. ACL Component is a tool to setup perrmisions (`$this->Acl->allow` , `$this->Acl->denay` ect...) or check permissions `$this->Acl->check`...
If you wish to dig deepper into this subject I recommend to go through [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)  tutorial ...

Comment: So in most cases we would want to use both, right? Ok thanks, earlier I was under the impression that they are standalone modules, able to be used one without the other.